# Looking for year-by-year worldwide ethanol production data

Tags: data-request, global, energy, industry

What is the total worldwide ethanol production? I want any ethanol, **for any purposes**, including human consumption (drinking alcohol) and fuel and chemical industry.

I want to see how much total ethanol is produced, and **compare how much is produced for fuel vs how much is produced for drinking.** It should be interesting to see which is bigger. I also want year by year accounts to see any trends.

I have searched for this myself but the data is not trustworthy unless it explicitly explains ethanol for what purpose.

For example, [This Site](https://www.afdc.energy.gov/data/10331) says US is biggest producer at 15B gallons in 2015, but it's in the context of ethanol fuel and doesn't say explicitly "15B gallons of ethanol for all purposes". In fact if you look down, it says "The vast majority of U.S. ethanol is produced from corn..." I am pretty sure if you throw drinking alcohol in the mix, the biggest source is gonna be grapes (for wine) and hops (for beer).

Other examples, [Wikipedia: Beer in US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer_in_the_United_States) says the US produced 23B liters (6.1B gallons) of beer in 2012. I guess I have to guess at the average ethanol content, which I'll guess at 20 proof, so 610M gallons of ethanol. [This site](https://www.statista.com/statistics/270275/worldwide-beer-production/) says 196B liters (51.8B gallons) of beer was produced worldwide in 2015, but again, no mention of average ethanol content.

Comment: [faostat](http://www.fao.org/faostat/en/) may have the numbers, but you'd have to combine various sources

Comment: Hops is only a minor ingredient in beer, used for flavor and as a preservative. The main ingredient in beer is grain, which can be barley, wheat, corn, etc. Anything that provides carbohydrates to feed the yeast. And many kinds of hard liquor are made from corn, because it's cheap. For example, vodka (which is traditionally made from potatoes) is often made from corn.